# World background is not being rendered

Tags: animation, world

I cannot seem to render the world background even though I have set the transparency and the alpha channel.

How can I solve this?

[image: Transparency]

I have uploaded a blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the Transparent checkbox you effectively make the world background invisible. If you want to have the background visible in the render it must be unchecked.

Comment: Huh, and a lot of the resources pointed out that this option should be _checked_. Maybe I misunderstood but now it works. Thank you :)